# How to display results in a laravel controller in Vue Template?

Tags: vue.js, laravel-vue

Please I have a return values in inside an array in a Laravel Controller. I want to display the in a Vue Template but am having Issue. I need Assistance please.

```
    public function search(Request $request)
    {  
      $batchResults = \DB::table('patient')
                            ->select('*')
                            ->join('registrations', 'patient.patient_id', 'registrations.patient_id')
                            ->where('patient.name', 'like', '%' . $request -> name . '%')
                            ->whereBetween('registrations.created_at', [date($request->from), date($request->to)])        
                            ->get();

                        $search = $request -> name;


                        return [ $batchResults, $batchResults ];
```

I want to dispaly ***[ $batchResults, $batchResults ]*** resut in vue Template

this is the console.log results

```
(2) [Array(1), "James Asay", __ob__: Observer]
0: [{…}, __ob__: Observer]
1: "James Asaye"
length: 2
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(2), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
```

***Vue Component***

```
searchBatch(){
          axios.post('/search-results', this.form).then((res)=>{
            this.batchResource = res.data
            this.display = true

            console.log(res.data)
          })
        }
```

Comment: Could you also post a bit of the vue component / vue template so we can see what is happening on that side?

Comment: Please I have update it

Comment: and the template, have you tried {{ batchResource }} inside your template?

Comment: ``` <tr v-for="batch in batchResource" :key="batch.id">
      <th scope="row">{{batch.patient_number}}</th>
      <td>{{batch.patient_name}} | {{batch.patient_gender}}</td></tr> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, one useful strategy to debugging these sorts of problems,
in your template add:

```
<pre>{{$data}}</pre>
```

So you can see all the data that is available to you in your template.

As for why it isn't working. You receive batchResource from your server which is an array: `[ $batchResult, $batchResult ]`,

Either change your searchBatch function to adapt to this situation, like so:

```
searchBatch(){
   axios.post('/search-results', this.form).then((res)=>{
  
   // res.data = [ $batchResult, $batchResult ]
   // take the first list of results:
   this.batchResource = res.data[0]
   this.display = true

   console.log(res.data)
   })
}
```

Or don't change the search function and deal with it in your template:

```
<tr v-for="batch in batchResource[0]" :key="batch.id">
    <th scope="row">{{batch.patient_number}}</th>
    <td>{{batch.patient_name}} | {{batch.patient_gender}}</td>
</tr>
```